# c++: function lvalue or rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

I just started learning about rvalue references in c++11 by reading [this page](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html), but I got stuck into the very first page. Here is the code I took from that page.

```
  int& foo();
  foo() = 42; // ok, foo() is an lvalue
  int* p1 = &foo(); // ok, foo() is an lvalue

  int foobar();
  j = foobar(); // ok, foobar() is an rvalue
  int* p2 = &foobar(); // error, cannot take the address of an rvalue
```

1. why is `foo()` an lvalue? is it because `foo()` returns `int&` which is basically an lvalue?
2. why is `foobar()` an rvalue? is it because `foobar()` returns `int`?
3. In general, why would you care if a function is an rvalue or not? I think if I read the rest of that article, I'll get my answer to this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

L-Values are locations, R-Values are *storable* values (i.e., values that can be assigned: namespaces, for instance, are **not** assignable; thanks to @Maggyero for the edit suggestion).

So:

1. since `foo()` returns a reference(`int&`), that makes it an lvalue itself.
2. Correct. `foobar()` is an rvalue because `foobar()` returns `int`.
3. We don't care that much if a function is an R-Value or not.  What we are getting excited about is R-Value references.

The article you pointed to is interesting and I had not considered forwarding or the use in factories before.  The reason I was excited about R-Value references was the move semantics, such as this:

```
BigClass my_function (const int& val, const OtherClass & valb);

BigClass x;
x = my_function(5, other_class_instance);
```

In that example, x is destroyed, then the return of my_function is copied into x with a copy constructor. To get around that historically, you would write:

```
void my_function (BigClass *ret, const int& val, const OtherClass & valb);

BigClass x;
my_function(&x, 5, other_class_instance);
```

which means that now `my_function` has side effects, plus it isn't as plain to read. Now, with C++11, we can instead write:

```
BigClass & my_function (const int& val, const OtherClass & valb);

BigClass x;
x = my_function(5, other_class_instance);
```

And have it operate as efficiently as the second example.

Comment: ‘R-Values are actual values’ More precisely, R-values are *storable* values. Some values cannot be assigned in C++ and therefore are not R-values, e.g. a type, a namespace.

Comment: @Maggyero namespaces and types aren't values at all. Not everything with a name is a value

Comment: @Caleth A value is the meaning of an expression. Since namespaces and types are not meaningless, they do have a value. You may have a look at Dana Scott and Christopher Strachey’s work on denotational semantics. I don’t think that a denotational semantics for C++ has been published though. For the moment it is only specified in natural language in the ISO C++ standard.

Comment: @Maggyero the C++ standard talks about values in [basic.lval](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lval), namespaces and types are not expressions (though namespace names and type names can appear with an expression) "The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression. The result of a prvalue is the value that the expression stores into its context; a prvalue that has type cv void has no result. A prvalue whose result is the value V is sometimes said to have or name the value V."

Comment: @Caleth A [*value*](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3232/PRG10.pdf) (or *denotation*) in denotational semantics is what is called an [*entity*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.pre#3) in the terminology of the ISO C++ standard. And a [*stored value*](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3232/PRG10.pdf) (or *stored denotation*) in denotational semantics is what is called a [*value*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.pre#3) in the ISO C++ standard. Namespaces and types are values in the terminology of denotational semantics and entities in that of the ISO C++ standard.

Comment: @Maggyero and we are talking about C++, not denotational semantics. Use the definitions in the C++ standard

Comment: @Caleth Yes I should have given more context, sorry for the confusion.